# Match Data in Excel to one of three Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to match information that could be in one of three columns - and show up anywhere in the column.

Input:

```
 ID #   Possible ID 1   Possible ID 2   Possible ID 3
 0021   0004            6304            0004            
 0030   0021            0021            0021            
 0033   0030            2330            0030            
 0034   0038            0338            0038           
 8410   0110            8410            0110
```

For the result, I need to know the information in Column A (ID#), along with the value in the matched Possible ID field (0021,0021 or 8410,110)

I need to validate hundreds of records and don't quite know how to check all three of the "Possible ID" fields to get the correct values.

Output:

```
 ID #   Possible ID 1   Possible ID 2   Possible ID 3   Result
 0021   0004            6304            0004            ?
 0030   0021            0021            0021            ?
 0033   0030            2330            0030            ?
 0034   0038            0338            0038            ?
 8410   0110            8410            0110            ?
```

Comment: Do you want the first match found or all relevant?

Comment: I need to always have the value in the Possible ID 3 field. It doesn't matter if it's the first match or the most relevant

Comment: What does the input look like and how do you want the output, one cell comma delimited, multiple cells?

Comment: The input is simply the information as they exist in the columns. I don't care if the output is in one cell, comma separated or in two cells.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some expected results?  Do you just want to know if the A2 matches B2, C2, or D2 (for each row) or do you want to know if A2 matches any value in columns B,C or D?  When there is a match, what information do you want? Just TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: I need A2 to match B:B, C:C or D:D. I need the value from A2 and the match result from either column B, C or D.

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional information from me.

Comment: When there is a match, what information do you want? Just TRUE/FALSE indicating that there is a match in some row of columns B,C,D?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a simple TRUE/FALSE result, use:

```
=OR(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,B:B,1))),NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1))),NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,D:D,1))))
```

For the first row, then copy down the rows which will alter the A2 to A3, A4, etc...

```
 ID #   Possible ID 1   Possible ID 2   Possible ID 3   Result
 0021   0004            6304            0004            TRUE
 0030   0021            0021            0021            TRUE
 0033   0030            2330            0030            FALSE
 0034   0038            0338            0038            FALSE
 8410   0110            8410            0110            TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, Degan - If possible, I need both values, rather than a True/False: 

I'm attempting to match information that could be in one of three columns - and show up anywhere in the column.

enter image description here

If possible, I'd like to know the information in Column A (ID#), along with the value in the matched Possible ID 1, 2 or 3 field (0021,0021 or 8410,110).

Comment: Jody, I appreciate the reply, but it is still unclear to me.  If the values "match" to me this means that they are equal.  Does this mean something different to you?  If they are equal, then the ID# column will be the same as the value in the matching Possible ID 1,2, or 3 column.  Do you want the ID# value returned twice?  Again, a sample output would be helpful to me or anyone else attempting to answer your question.  Perhaps copy/paste my results table, updating the results to those you desire?